# I am getting as 'bound method NDFrame.head of ' while displaying output in python jupytr notebook

Tags: python, function, eval, head

I tried using - assetDf.eval('pop') , pop but it shows no functions exists.
How to get all values without 'bound method NDFrame.head of '.
Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackOverflow. Could you provide a minimum code that can be run ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask